# Raspberry pi froze, unplugged it, and now nothing is working

Tags: hdmi

My raspberry pi froze while I was trying to find a module on firefox, and I found another question that said to unplug it, so I did and now that i plugged it back in, the monitor is blank, and the red light isnt there. Just the green one.

Comment: Methodically work through http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting and report the results.